# Translating text blocks with Django .. what to do with the HTML?

Tags: django

The title might not be clear, but I don't know how else to put it..

In the Django documentation it's pretty clear how to mark a text block for translation .. Take this example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec quam sem, sodales in fringilla nec, lacinia a lorem. 
Vivamus vel molestie ante.
```

So far so good. You just either use the trans or blocktrans tag.

But now consider this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec quam sem, sodales in fringilla nec, lacinia a lorem. 
<a href="{% url some-view %}">Vivamus vel</a> molestie ante.
```

How should I deal with this ? Do I just wrap it in a block trans ?

**Edit:**

I think I've found out how it should be done ..

```
{% url some-view as some_view_url %}
{% blocktrans %}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec quam sem, sodales in fringilla nec, lacinia a lorem. 
<a href="{{ some_view_url }}">Vivamus vel</a> molestie ante.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would definitely use blocktrans. Sometimes its not possible to split i18n html text into different fragments. Blocktrans has some powerfull features:

```
{% url path.to.view arg arg2 as the_url %}

{% blocktrans with object.title as title and author|title as author_t %}

  {{author}}: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Donec quam sem, sodales in fringilla nec, lacinia a lorem. 
  <a href="{{the_url}}">{{title}}</a> molestie ante.

{% endblocktrans %}
```

Have a look at:

- [url template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url)
- [blocktrans template-tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag)

Comment: is there a way to NOT write `<a href="{{url}}">{{blah}}</a>` - I don't want translators to add HTML. It would be nicer to have `{% blocktranslate %} This is a link to {{ link }}.{% endblocktranslate %}`. Any chance? (yes, I know I can generate this in the view before, but in the template?)