# How do I keep inline links within django translations?

Tags: python, django

I've successfully installed Django's translation system but have run up to what appears to be a design flaw (and hopefully I'm wrong).

It's easy to create translation blocks as such

```
<p>{% trans "The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain" %}</p>
```

But in some cases, I want just part of the sentence to be a link or have different formatting.

```
<p>The rain in <a href="...">Spain</a> falls <strong>mainly</strong> on the plain</p>
```

I realize, I could just create translation blocks within those tags as such

```
<p>
  {% trans "The rain in " %}
  <a href="...">{% trans "Spain" %}</a>
  {% trans " falls mainly " %}
  <strong>{% trans "on the plain" %}</strong>
</p>
```

But not only does that make it irritating to translators, it forces a word order that is not guaranteed by the target language.

I've looked at more robust translation solutions like https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta
But I don't see anything in the docs about it accounting for this usage. Is there some HTML trick I can use here?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`blocktrans`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-blocktrans):

```
<p>
  {% blocktrans %}
  The rain in <a href="...">Spain</a>
  falls mainly <strong>on the plain</strong>
  {% endblocktrans %}
</p>
```

It allows more complex contents than the simple `trans`, which can mostly only be used with standard text. Note that [reverse `url` lookups are not supported](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7239) within the `blocktrans` tag, so you'll have to save the URLs to a variable before entering the `blocktrans`, [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397360/716118).