# Django i18n translating text with html

Tags: django, django-templates

What to do with HTML in translations? I want to translate sentences with HTML in them. For example such a string (`[login]` is a link):

```
Please [login] to view your profile.
```

I do not want to bother my translators with translating text with html intertwined. On the other hand, I do not want to bother with creating all the links in my views, like suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397218/translating-text-blocks-with-django-what-to-do-with-the-html). So ideally I want a template-only solution to have the flexibility of crafting HTML, while allowing translators to only work with text strings.

For example, this pseudocode implements these requirements:

```
{% render as login_html %}
    <a href="{{ url 'login' }}?next={{ request.path|urlencode }}">
        {% trans "Login" %}
    </a>
{% endrender %}

{% blocktrans with login=login_html %}
    Please {{ login }} to view your profile.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

First, the login HTML is rendered and stored as `login_url`. Then in my blocktrans, I can simply use `{{ login }}` to give the rendered login HTML. Is there a (similar) solution to this problem, or would it require custom template tags?

Comment: Your solution translates twice.

Comment: Why is that? `{{ login }}` is a variable and would not be translated (again).

Comment: Except that's not how template i18n works.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a generic `render` tag to do just that:

```
from classytags.arguments import Argument, Flag
from classytags.core import Options
from classytags.helpers import AsTag
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()


class Render(AsTag):
    """
    Renders the block contents to be used elsewhere in the template.

    Example usage:

        {% render as login_url %}
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}">{% trans "Login" %}</a>
        {% endrender %}

        {% blocktrans %}
            Please {{ login_url }} for more information.
        {% endblocktrans %}

    It will automatically strip leading and trailing whitespace, use `nowrap`
    to disable this behaviour:

        {% render nostrip as varname %} . . . {% endrender %}
    """
    options = Options(
        Flag('strip', default=True, false_values=['nostrip']),
        'as',
        Argument('varname', resolve=False, required=True),
        blocks=[('endrender', 'nodelist')],
    )

    def get_value(self, context, nodelist, strip, **kwargs):
        value = nodelist.render(context)
        if strip:
            value = value.strip()
        return mark_safe(value)
register.tag(Render)
```

When used with translation contexts (e.g. `{% trans "Login" context "login_url" %}`), the translator will have great control over the translation while still not being bothered with HTML.

```
msgctxt "login_url"
msgid "Login"
msgstr ""

#, python-format
msgid "Please %(login_url)s for more information."
msgstr ""
```

Comment: It depends on django-classy-tags: https://github.com/django-cms/django-classy-tags