# Can Django trans tags include HTML tags?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-1.8, django-tagging

Can Django trans tags include HTML tags? For example can I do `{% trans "Hold <em><strong>Ctrl</strong></em>" %}` ? Or would I have to do `{% trans "Hold" %} <em><strong>{% trans "Ctrl" %}</strong></em>"` instead?

Answer (score 14):

**Can we include HTML tags inside the `trans` template tags?**

**No,** we should not include HTML tags inside a [`trans`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag) template tag as you are doing in your 1st approach `{% trans "Hold <em><strong>Ctrl</strong></em>" %}` . This is a wrong approach

From the [docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag)

> The `{% trans %}` template tag translates either a constant string
>   (enclosed in single or double quotes) or variable content.
>
> It’s not possible to mix a template variable inside a string within `{% trans %}`. **If your translations require strings with variables
>   (placeholders), use `{% blocktrans %}` instead.**

```
<title>{% trans "This is the title." %}</title> # example 1

<title>{% trans "myvar" noop %}</title>  # example 2
```

**Solution-1: Using `trans` template tag**

Instead of putting HTML code inside the `trans` tag, you can do something like below to get the desired result(though this is not the recommended approach).

```
{% trans "Hold" %} <em><strong>{% trans "Ctrl" %}</strong></em> # using trans tag
```

**Solution-2: Using [`blocktrans`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag) tag instead**

Better option is to use `blocktrans` template tag instead of `trans` tag to include the HTML tags.

> the `blocktrans` tag allows you to mark complex sentences consisting of
>   literals and variable content for translation by making use of
>   placeholders:

You can then just do:

```
{% blocktrans %}
Hold <em><strong>Ctrl</strong></em>
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to accord with the DRY principle.

Comment: To some extent you can say.

Comment: Quite a bit in my case.

Comment: @RahulGupta I'm confused by this. What does the ability to mix variables and strings have to with including HTML tags (which are just constant strings)?  Which is to say, you should be able to include them just fine, but you need to make sure they're translated correctly (i.e. not translated in most cases) ;)

Comment: Solution one isn't really correct, it doesn't make sense to translate the words independently if they are part of a sentence. E.g: some languages need them to be the other way around ("Ctrl" and then "Hold").

Answer (score 2):

As Rahul said in his answer, one should not include HTML tags inside a trans template tag. However, according to [Translating text blocks with Django .. what to do with the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397218/translating-text-blocks-with-django-what-to-do-with-the-html) (which I just found), one can put HTML tags inside of blocktrans template tags instead. Thus I don't have to do `{% trans "Hold" %} <em><strong>{% trans "Ctrl" %}</strong></em>"`. I was unable to find such instructions in [the Django 1.8 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag).

Comment: Yes, we can't use HTML tags inside a `trans` template tag but we can use `blocktrans` tag. The solution using `trans` template is not the best solution. We can use the `blocktrans` template tag instead for our case. I have updated the ans, please check.